# How can I have one content type be a child of another content type in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-7, entity-relationship

I would like to create a new content type `Family` in drupal. I would then like for that content type to have fields which ask you to choose from a list of `Child` where `Child` is another custom content type.

Furthermore, I'd like to restrict the choose child field to only show children for which content has been created.

**Example:** I'd like to create a new `Family` based on the `Family` content type. Then while I'm creating the family, I'd like for it to ask me what children I want, and I can choose from Bob, John or Sarah all of which are previously created content of content type `Child`.

I installed the [Relation module](http://drupal.org/project/relation) but I don't understand how it works so I'm not sure if this is what I need or if I can achieve this somehow with taxonomy or something in Drupal core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the Relationship module as I have not used it, but it is definitely worth your time to look at the [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references).  This is pretty much a port of the node reference and user reference field types that were a part of CCK in Drupal 6.  It installs new field types you can use in your content types.

Once you install the module (be sure to install Node Reference) you can add a node reference field to your "Family" content type and allow it to only reference nodes from the "Child" content type.

Comment: interesting, the references module link says: "A new, promising approach for entity relationships in D7 is being worked on in the Relation module" so I might try to make that one work, but good to know this is a solid backup.